# Webpack not resolving relative paths in imported CSS files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

I am currently working on building a set of UI modules that developers can use to create content on their sites (similar to Bootstrap, Foundation etc). Each UI module is created as its own npm package and a developer will then pull the required modules into their project via npm.

I have a components-accordion package which contains just the CSS for an accordion. It has a file structure as follows:

```
/lib
/build
/node_modules
index.css
package.json
```

The **index.css** file shown above consists of a relative link to the lib directory where the actual styles for the component live:

```
./lib/accordion.css
```

I have been testing this package with a React Accordion project and have imported it for the styles. However the relative paths in this package seem to not be correctly resolved by Webpack.

```
import "components-accordion";
```

gives an error:

**Failed to compile.
./src/components/Accordion.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components-accordion' in ...**

If I link to the index.css file directly:

```
import "components-accordion/index.css";
```

**../components-accordion/index.css
Module not found: Can't resolve './lib/accordion' in...**

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your webpack configuration to include the `lib` folder as part of webpack modules, using `path`

```or-tag-here
const path = require("path");
resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib')
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Hmm still getting the same error unfortunately. Module not found: Can't resolve './lib/accordion' in ...

Comment: could you share the parent folder of the component-accordion package. And could you please tell me if it is installed with npm install ? Is that an npm package ? If so, could you try
as follows:  import "~/components-accordion/index.css";